# PHP - Insert into table with name of previous select statement result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I am trying to insert into a mySql table, the tables name is the result of a sql select query, the first query returns the correct result but the second query is where the error seems to lie, any help would be very very much appreciated

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT council from users where username = '$username'");

 $x = mysql_result($query,0, "council");
 $councilArea = (string)$x;


// mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$councilArea' ('barcode', 'productname', 'bin', 'info', 'addedby') VALUES('$barcode', '$productname', '$bin', '$info', '$username')");
```

Comment: The error results from single-quoting `'$councilArea'` and all of the column names like `'barcode'` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks. Table & column names should not be quoted (unless they are reserved words, requiring backticks)

Comment: But this also points to a larger problem with your database design.  Rather than storing the _name_ of a table holding related information, you ought to be storing a column in a single table which is a foreign key.  In other words, your design implies that you have several similar tables when you should have one table with a differentiating column against which you can perform join queries.

Comment: this is part of a JSON response, it proceeds with an if statment checking if the result is populated, if not, return unsuccessful, it returns unsuccessful each time and nothing populated in the database.

Comment: Finally, review [how can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Your use of the deprecated `mysql_*()` extension is potentially unsafe.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I wrote in the answer, what you put in the comment, but I did not copy on your comments,

Comment: Thanks Michael, problem was quotes. I thought I tried each combination. As for the design, it is just a prototype representing other databases and just put them into tables. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because a table name must not be quoted by single quotes, but by backticks.

There is also a fundamental problem with your database design. 
You save data in different tables, that really should be stored in one table. 
Add a field *counselArea* in the table to distinguish the data, instead of storing it in different tables.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The design is just for a prototype. Thanks for the reply.